# Aggregated query returning 1s where 0's are expected

Tags: mysql, select, left-join

In my devices table, `is_muted` is 0 for all 4 rows:

[image]

yet when I run the following query:

```
SELECT
    devices.id,
    devices.hostname,
    devices.last_seen_at,
    devices.is_muted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN events.is_healthy = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_checks_unhealthy
FROM devices
LEFT JOIN events ON events.devices_id = devices.id
GROUP BY devices.id
```

it returns `is_muted` as 1 for all devices.

[image]

Yet if I remove `devices.hostname` from the query, is_muted returns correctly:

```
SELECT
    devices.id,
    devices.is_muted,
    SUM(CASE WHEN events.is_healthy = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS num_checks_unhealthy
FROM devices
LEFT JOIN events ON events.devices_id = devices.id
GROUP BY devices.id
```

[image]

or if I leave devices.hostname in the SELECT but remove the JOIN, it also returns correctly:

```
SELECT
    devices.id,
    devices.hostname,
    devices.is_muted
FROM devices
GROUP BY devices.id
```

[image]

Can someone please help me figure out what am I misunderstanding? Why does `is_muted` return 1 rather than 0 when I select another random TEXT column from the same table, or use a JOIN? Where is the 1 coming if all values in the `is_muted` column are 0?

### Update

Selecting is_muted in an IF statement is returning the expected data:

```
SELECT 
  devices.id,
  devices.hostname,
  devices.last_seen_at,
  IF(devices.is_muted = 1, TRUE, FALSE) AS muted,
sum(case when events.is_healthy = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS num_checks_unhealthy,
sum(case when events.is_healthy = 1 then 1 else 0 end) AS num_checks_healthy
FROM devices
LEFT JOIN events ON events.devices_id = devices.id
GROUP BY devices.id
```

[image]

I tested this by muting one device and verified the response:

[image]

Comment: Is `devices.id` the primary key of the table?

Comment: @Barmar yes it is, AI primary key

Comment: I don't see any way this can happen. Can you reproduce it at a site like sqlfiddle.com?

Comment: It sounds like the table may be corrupted, try `REPAIR TABLE`.

Comment: I've just installed MySQL on a sandbox machine and imported the DB and it's not happening on there... so I'm wondering if it's an issue with a specific MySQL version or the config!

Comment: @Barmar I tried the repair but had the same issue. I've just had a look at the MySQL config of the device this is failing on and the only difference I can see between that box and the working device is that this server has `only_full_group_by` SQL mode enabled

Comment: That's not a problem, since `is_muted` is uniquely determined by the `GROUP BY` column. You would get an error if you violed that restriction.

Comment: I have disabled only_full_group_by SQL mode on the problematic server and removed the GROUP BY (just as a test) and it's working as expected... not sure why or what to do next.

Comment: Updated question with working example (with only_full_group_by mode enabled again)

Comment: It sounds like a MySQL bug.

Comment: If every device_id can only have a single value for is_muted, then put the is_muted into an aggregate.  so MIN(is_muted) or MAX(is_muted).  I guess the "ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY" may be disable.  So it is returning a nondeterministic result.

Comment: @KevinHorgan Why is it non-deterministic? There's only one row per `devices.id`, since it's the primary key.

Comment: But using the aggregate may be a good workaround.

Comment: Thanks for looking at this with me, not sure what I should do with this question now. I've got my 'fix' but I still don't know the root cause...

Comment: @Barmar, by disabling ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY a non aggregate column can be selected that is not in the GROUP BY but the value used is not functionally dependent on the GROUP BY.  So if the column only has a single value then that is fine, otherwise you can get a value you do not expect.  In this case the value 1 instead of 0.

Comment: @KevinHorgan But the column *is* functionally dependent on the GROUP BY, since he's grouping by the primary key.

Comment: @Barmar, sorry I missed the comment about the primary key above.  In that case I would either try adding the aggregator MAX(is_muted) for example, or expand the GROUP BY to include the other columns from the devices table not aggregated like is_muted.

Comment: I did try expanding the GROUP BY to include the other devices columns but didn't get the expected result. MAX(is_muted) makes sense, and I guess would be a faster/cheaper query than using the `IF()` statement shown in my update?